# How can there be stationary points of fluid in Pitot tubes?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

In the context of fluid dynamics and the use of Pitot tubes, it is important to know the points where the fluid doesn't move in order to measure the total pressure.

However, aren't the concept of points not moving and the continuity principle in an incompressible flow contradictory?

How would it be possible to explain both?

Answer (score 1):

Pitot tubes are basically two holes:

- one is aligned with the flow and gets the "full pressure"  (total pressure) of the flow i.e. the pressure as we all know it from the weather forecast (static pressure) plus the pressure due to the velocity of the flow impinging on the pitot (dynamic pressure);
- one hole is perpendicular to the flow and therefore gets only the static pressure (the flow just pass by without entering this hole).

This picture ([source](https://www.instpedia.com/Flow-En.php)) shows it a good way:

[image: pitot tube schematic]

If the flow is incompressible (liquid or gas at Mach number lower than some 0.3), the total pressure of the flow as measured by the first hole can be evaluated mathematically and equals:

$p_{tot}=p_s + ½ \rho V²$

The second hole gets as said only $p_s$ and from the difference of the two we get then the $½ \rho V²$ part i.e. the part proportional to the speed.